# Duplicate Username error on upsert/insert action

Tags: data, error-messages, migration, insert, data-migration

Let me explain from the start.
I gave users data to insert in UAT org (records contain an external ID). I asked them to insert data and there were 3000+ records. He mistakenly closed the window and till now there were only 1300 records that have been inserted.
I asked them to upsert the data based on the external ID column. This time only 3 more records were inserted and the rest of them threw the error:

```
"DUPLICATE_USERNAME: Duplicate Username.<br>The username already exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email address).  [Username]"
```

I tried to find the username in UAT org and nothing was found.
I tried inserting 5 failed records separately, but got the same error.

I have inserted the records in DEV org and SIT so I know how to change the username according to the org I am inserting in.

Comment: Username should be unique across all salesforce orgs. Can you share a username example? Generally as a good practice, we always add sandbox name at the end of the email, to make the username unique. For eg : If sandbox name is `xyz` then username of users in this org would be `somename@abc.com.xyz`

Comment: For Dev org abc@email.com.dev, for SIT org abc@email.com.sit, for UAT org abc@email.com.uat. This way I inserted the records in Dev and SIT org, but getting error for UAT

Comment: If you get a DUPLICATE_USERNAME error, but you can't find the username on any of your orgs, someone else has already taken it, and there's only one thing to do: come up with another username. "dev" and "uat" are not suffixes likely to make the names unique.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce usernames are unique, for all users, across all production or sandbox organizations and instances. A username can exist in both sandbox and production but duplicates are not allowed in each instance type.

Usernames are shared across instances, but not across environments (production/sandbox). I.e. if a user account in a sandbox instance has username = a@b.c, this username cannot be used in any other sandbox instance (CS*), but it can be used in production instances (NA*, EU*, AP*)

There are 3 reasons why this might happen :

1. Previous Sandbox Not Properly Deleted - Usernames are unique across
   all  production or sandbox instances. If the previous sandbox did
   not delete  properly, it will retain the username and cause a
   conflict in the new  sandbox.
2. Username Replication Delays - This can happen when a newly refreshed
   org and old org are on different instances, as it takes a while for
   the user info to be replicated in the new org.
3. Someone else (globally) has already taken the username you are using it.

If you want to double-check those usernames exists in some environment globally you can create a case with Salesforce Support so that they can check from backend and help you to check this as they will be able to provide more information on this issue and if needed can help you further as well.

Comment: Thanks, guys for the responses, I just changed all the usernames and it worked

Comment: @PriyanshKumar - you should accept Ravi's answer as a service to the community